# What is the difference between INTERVAL '0 days' and '0 days'::INTERVAL in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a basic table with a list of dates in psql using a loop. The code is shown below

```
DO $$

DECLARE counter       INTEGER :=0;
    date_interval VARCHAR(250) :='0 DAYS';

BEGIN


  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_dates;
  CREATE TABLE temp_dates (
    date DATE
  );

  WHILE counter < 12 LOOP

    date_interval := counter || ' DAYS';

    INSERT INTO temp_dates
    --SELECT DATE_TRUNC('DAYS', CURRENT_DATE) - date_interval :: INTERVAL;
      SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('DAYS', CURRENT_DATE)) - (INTERVAL date_interval);

    counter := counter + 1;
END LOOP;

END $$;
```

In the above query

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('DAYS', CURRENT_DATE) - date_interval :: INTERVAL;
```

works. But the following does not work

```
SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('DAYS', CURRENT_DATE)) - (INTERVAL date_interval);
```

Basically the only difference date_interval :: INTERVAL vs INTERVAL date_interval

But it works when I directly do something like INTERVAL '2 days' but it fails when I use a variable.

So my question is two fold

1. What is the difference between INTERVAL '2 days' and '2 days'::INTERVAL. From what I understand both are typecasting.
2. Why does INTERVAL '2 days' work but it fails when using a variable

I am sure I am missing something fairly obvious when it comes to escaping quotation marks but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) states clearly, the syntax

```
INTERVAL '0 days'
```

is for constants, that is, the string has to be a literal.

It is *not* a syntax for type casts like `'0 days'::interval`, which allow you to change the type of an arbitrary expression.